# Shading Elastic search high level java rest client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, lucene, gradle-shadow-plugin

Can I shade high level rest client? bascially I want to use latest Elastic Search Rest client (7.4) and Lucene 5.3.0 (Legacy) in my project.

It's possible with Low level client ([link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-shading.html)), I want to know if it's available for High level client.

Comment: I doubt this will work. I'd rather put the effort into upgrading Elasticsearch since you won't get around that anyway. Trying to hack together a client that might work rather than doing the upgrade doesn't sound like a win in the long run.

Comment: I was planning if it's possible to move to ES in stages, but adding ES client dependancy fails to compile the project altogether.
Either I'll have to migrate Lucene code to latest version (8.2.0) which is used by ES or remove all Lucene code.
Fat/Uber jar would have made my life easier here until we move the entire project.

Comment: @AbhishekS, it's totally possible and some days ago, I also ran into similar issue and we also want to move to ES in phases, I asked similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739284/run-two-versions-of-elasticsearch-in-java-application-using-maven and found the solution but couldn't update the answer. will try to provide the answer here, let me know which build tool you are usin

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal: I'm using Gradle, please update your answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: @AbhishekS, I used maven and not much familer with gradle :(

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal: Nevertheless please do update your answer with findings, I'll try to implement in Gradle.